# mk6 Golf - cam shaft sensor wire broken (I think)

Tags: vw, golf, tdi

I drove my golf for around 500 miles on Monday, 8/22, I tried to use it after that and the car wouldn't turn on. I tried a few things and googles and finally found that this wire, which I believe to be connected to the cam shaft sensor, to be broken off from the connector. I also found a piece of plastic that looks like it was supposed to hold the connector to a bigger tube.

The wires were damaged at first and when I was trying to access the connection I ended up pulling the broken wires out of the connector:

[image]
[image]

Is there anyway I can repair, at least get this car started in my driveway to drive it to a shop? I'm not a mechanic and this looks expensive.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you went to fix this, I think your best bet is to soldier a piece of wire in place between the wires. The connector side is so short, I don't see any other way you'd get it semi-fixed.

On the other hand, you can usually find replacement connectors for things like this. There'd be a pigtail of wire on them you'd then splice into your existing harness.

Either way, with some simple tools, you should be able to repair it well enough to get you down the road.

Comment: Yeah, I can't really access it. I think I'd have to take the turbo off to get to it. Is that an involved process? 
I didn't know they make those connectors, I'll start looking for them.

Comment: Taking the turbo off could be very involved for the uninitiated. If you can take the connector off from it's home, then pull the wire back some, you might be able to attempt a fix on the old connector. With a new connector, you just need the end from the wiring harness and it becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Maybe it got somehow put into a bad location b/c there doesn't seem to be any slack on it. I took a look at the photo of the overall harness, maybe I can get at it from a better way. I found the cable too, thank you!